# How do I get Visual Studio to place the unit tests where I want them?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-4.0, resharper, mstest

In both VSTS 2008 and VS 2010 RC1 when I create a Unit Test (mstest), I am not asked where I would like the project to be placed.  It will always turn up at the Solution level.  I would like to place the test project inside the folder of the class(es) that are being tested.

I have tried unloading the unit test project and adding it to the class library, but that breaks the coupling with the class.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RC1 with ReSharper 5.0 and Visual Stuido 2008 with RS 4.5.

TIA,
Jim

Amended:  I was not at all clear about placing the unit tests.  I have a Solution with several Solution Folders.  One of these is a common library.  I would like to add unit tests for some classes in the library.  VS will place the TestProject at the base Solution level.  I would prefer

mySolution
mySolution\SolutionFolder
mySolution\SolutionFolder\ClassLibrary
mySolution\SolutionFolder\ClassLibrary\Class1.cs
mySolution\SolutionFolder\ClassLibrary\Class2.cs
mySolution\SolutionFolder\UnitTestForClass1
mySolution\SolutionFolder\UnitTestFOrClass2

Instead, VS will do:

mySolution
mySolution\SolutionFolder
mySolution\SolutionFolder\ClassLibrary
mySolution\SolutionFolder\ClassLibrary\Class1.cs
mySolution\SolutionFolder\ClassLibrary\Class2.cs
mySolution\UnitTestForClass1
mySolution\UnitTestFOrClass2

I hope this is clearer.  Thank you.
I do apologize for all the miss-edits I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal practice is to segregate byb source/source and source/test at the highest level.

In other words, suppose you have a "solution" with 3 projects, each of which builds a distinct assembly.  You might have a source tree like this:

```
soln\sourcesrc\proj1
soln\sourcesrc\proj2
soln\sourcesrc\proj3
```

The test code would normally be like this:

```
soln\testsrc\proj1
soln\testsrc\proj2
soln\testsrc\proj3
```

This is independent of Visual Studio or mstest.  This is just how I have seen it done, pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. In Delphi DUnit would create ut's under the folder with the classes.  I need to get used to the rest of the world, huh. :)

Answer (score 1):

Projects don't go inside of other projects with Visual Studio. Is there any other project type you've seen go inside of another project?